# error Attempted to read or write protected memory in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I have an error "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt"

If I debug x64 then an error appears but if I debug x86 then the error does not appear. I do not know what causes this issue in visual studio 2015 or in the code

```vb
Private Sub MenuItem1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    GeneratePayslip()
    report.ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub GeneratePayslip()
    Dim dir As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
    Dim filename As String = Path.Combine(dir, "LOGO.png")
    Dim table1 As New DataTable()
    Dim table2 As New DataTable()
    Dim table3 As New DataTable()
    Dim table4 As New DataTable()
    report.Clear()
    Dim query1 = "SELECT"
    Using adapter1 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query1, con)
        adapter1.Fill(table1)
    End Using
    Dim query2 = "SELECT"
    Using adapter2 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query2, con)
        adapter2.Fill(table2)
    End Using
    Dim query3 = "SELECT"
    Using adapter3 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query3, con)
        adapter3.Fill(table3)
    End Using
    Dim query4 = "SELECT" 
    Using adapter4 As New OleDbDataAdapter(query4, con)
        adapter4.Fill(table4)
    End Using
    For i = 0 To table1.Rows.Count - 1
        If i > 0 Then
            'We are not on the first row so we need a new page.
            report.NewPage()
        End If
        Dim row1 = table1.Rows(i)
        Dim row2 = table2.Rows(i)
        Dim row3 = table3.Rows(i)
        Dim row4 = table4.Rows(i)
        Dim tableCopy1 = {row1}.CopyToDataTable()
        Dim tableCopy2 = {row2}.CopyToDataTable()
        Dim tableCopy3 = {row3}.CopyToDataTable()
        Dim tableCopy4 = {row4}.CopyToDataTable()
        report.AddDataTable(tableCopy1)
        report.AddDataTable(tableCopy2)
        tableCopy1.Columns.Clear()
        tableCopy2.Columns.Clear()
        report.AddDataTable(tableCopy3)
        tableCopy3.Columns.Clear()
        report.AddDataTable(tableCopy4)
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: error]

Comment: What is `report`?  Since the issue is from `report.ShowPrintPreviewDialog`, the problem is probably with that component.  That's an error that usually indicates an issue in unmanaged code.

Comment: Printer drivers are always a good source of such misery.  Try selecting another one.

Comment: OT: Clearing the columns of those `DataTables` is pointless at best and could possibly cause issues, depending on how the report component is implemented. You never use those tables again so why do you think that clearing the columns is useful?

Comment: @Craig , sorry I'm late Reply. `report` is kimtoo.report library. `Since the issue is from report.ShowPrintPreviewDialog, the problem is probably with that component. That's an error that usually indicates an issue in unmanaged code. ` after I try on a different computer or CPU or machine there is no problem at all and on the cpu the problem is no problem if I debug with x86 so I guess this is a problem with the CPU

Comment: @HansPassant , after I try on a different computer or CPU or machine there is no problem at all and on the cpu the problem is no problem if I debug with x86 so I guess this is a problem with the CPU

Comment: @jmcilhinney , after I try on a different computer or CPU or machine there is no problem at all and on the cpu the problem is no problem if I debug with x86 so I guess this is a problem with the CPU